# Compare two values from a line of text then perform conditional task based on result

Tags: powershell, compare

I'm new to PowerShell, only written a couple basic scripts.
Here is what I'm attempting to do:
For the lines of text below, I want to compare the two values at the end of each line (see pstest.txt below)(50,20 line3 ; 20,50 line4) if the first value is higher than the second value then replace text on that line.

I've looked at several potential methods but can't find one that fits this scenario.

So far I have found a solution for replacing the specific text, and have figured out a method to retrieve values from specific lines for comparison but not sure how to proceed from here.
My objective is to modify only the line where the first "dimension" is greater than the second one.
When the condition is true add "T" after "5-STD", and trim the end of the line.
Then write the file over the original.
Below is my script, so far, I included a copy of the pstest.txt file for reference.

```
# $content = Get-Content "c:\temp\pstest.txt"
$line3 = Get-Content "c:\temp\pstest.txt" | Select-Object -Index 2 # get 1st line item (first 2 lines ignored)
$line4 = Get-Content "c:\temp\pstest.txt" | Select-Object -Index 3 # get 2st line item
$value1 = $line3.Substring(129,2) # gets the 1st dimension value from the 1st line item
$value2 = $line3.Substring(133,2) # gets the 2nd dimension value from the 1st line item
$value3 = $line4.Substring(129,2) # gets the 1st dimension value from the 2nd line item
$value4 = $line4.Substring(133,2) # gets the 2nd dimension value from the 2nd line item
Write-Host $value1, $value2 # displays values - test only
Write-Host $value3, $value4 # displays values - test only
# $content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"5-STD", ', '"5-STD",T'} | Set-Content "C:\temp\test.txt"
```

Pstest.txt

```
<V1.0>, "WinIG Import File"
*, "0918230406", "", "0918230406", "091823", "", ""
1, 1, 0, "CLAC-DSB-A", 50, 50, 0.875, "", "", "", "", 0.0, 0.0, "", "", "", "25504-6-1-IGU-TRAP 108279-1", "5-STD", , , 0.0, 20, 50, 20
2, 1, 0, "CLAC-DSB-A", 50, 50, 0.875, "", "", "", "", 0.0, 0.0, "", "", "", "25504-6-2-IGU-TRAP 108279-2", "5-STD", , , 0.0, 20, 20, 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with its `-File` and `-Regex` parameters for [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based line-by-line processing:

```bash
& {
  switch -Regex -File in.txt {
    '^(.+), (\d+), (\d+)$' {
      if ([int] $Matches.2 -gt [int] $Matches.3) {
        $Matches.1 + ',T'
      } else {
        $_ # pass through
      }
    }
    default { $_ } # pass through
  }
} |
  Set-Content out.txt
```

Note:

- The above assumes that all lines that end in two comma-separated decimal numbers are of interest.
- Regex `^(.+), (\d+), (\d+)$` matches such lines, and captures the substrings of interest via capture groups (`(...)`), with the results being reflected in the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches), with `$Matches.1` containing what the first capture group matched, `$Matches.2` the second, and so on.

  - For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/dJI63P/1).
- `switch`, due to being a *keyword* (language statement), cannot be used *directly* as pipeline input, hence the need to enclose it in a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) that is called via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)

  - If collecting all output first is acceptable, you could more simply write:

    ```bash
    # ... represent the `switch` statement above. 
    Set-Content out.txt $(...)
    ```
- Note that, generally speaking, you may have to use an `-Encoding` argument with [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content), because an input file's specific character encoding is never preserved in the PowerShell pipeline (the content is invariably decoded into .NET strings without storing information about the original encoding).

  - On saving (back) to a file, it is the chosen cmdlet's / redirection operator's *default* encoding that is applied.
  - Unfortunately, the defaults differ by cmdlet in *Windows PowerShell* (notably, ANSI for `Set-Content` and UTF-16LE ("Unicode") for `Out-File` / `>`), whereas *PowerShell (Core) 7+* now sensibly defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8.